# Pandas groupby with overlapping groups / windows

Tags: python, pandas

I suspect this use just isn't compatible with `groupby`, so maybe I'm actually asking for a different pattern that matches what I want. I have a dataframe of events w/ timespans and want to be able to iterate over/apply functions to the rows for each day. But if a row starts in one day and ends in another, I want that row to be included in both.

```
start = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2018-02-01 21:00:00',
                         end='2018-02-05, 21:00:00', freq='6h')
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': start.date, 'end': start.shift(1).date, 'value': 1}, 
                  columns=['start', 'end', 'value'])

         start         end  value
0   2018-02-01  2018-02-02      1
1   2018-02-02  2018-02-02      1
2   2018-02-02  2018-02-02      1
3   2018-02-02  2018-02-02      1
4   2018-02-02  2018-02-03      1
5   2018-02-03  2018-02-03      1
6   2018-02-03  2018-02-03      1
7   2018-02-03  2018-02-03      1
8   2018-02-03  2018-02-04      1
9   2018-02-04  2018-02-04      1
10  2018-02-04  2018-02-04      1
11  2018-02-04  2018-02-04      1
12  2018-02-04  2018-02-05      1
13  2018-02-05  2018-02-05      1
14  2018-02-05  2018-02-05      1
15  2018-02-05  2018-02-05      1
16  2018-02-05  2018-02-06      1
```

So the first group should contain `[0, ..., 4]`, then `[4, ..., 8]`, etc. In practice the events aren't evenly spaced so the lengths (in rows) of each day won't be constant.

The closest I've managed is starting with `groupby.indices` and manipulating the groups to match what I want, but this feels pretty gross.

```
{k: np.append(v[0] - 1, v) for k, v in df.groupby('start').indices.items() 
 if not (len(v) == 1 and v[0] == 0)}

{Timestamp('2018-02-02 00:00:00'): array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
 Timestamp('2018-02-03 00:00:00'): array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8]),
 Timestamp('2018-02-04 00:00:00'): array([ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12]),
 Timestamp('2018-02-05 00:00:00'): array([12, 13, 14, 15, 16])}
```

Comment: Do you mind to explain a little better your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to `aggregate`. There are many ways to go, for example

```
def e(inp):
    return [inp.index]

>>> df.groupby('end').aggregate(e)['start']

end
2018-02-02        [[0, 1, 2, 3]]
2018-02-03        [[4, 5, 6, 7]]
2018-02-04      [[8, 9, 10, 11]]
2018-02-05    [[12, 13, 14, 15]]
2018-02-06                [[16]]
Name: start, dtype: object
```

and

```
df.groupby('start').aggregate(e)['end']
start
2018-02-01                 [[0]]
2018-02-02        [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
2018-02-03        [[5, 6, 7, 8]]
2018-02-04     [[9, 10, 11, 12]]
2018-02-05    [[13, 14, 15, 16]]
Name: end, dtype: object
```

Now, you can play with these series, e.g. the following yields your output

```
merged = (df.groupby('end').aggregate(e)['start'] + df.groupby('start').aggregate(e)['end']).dropna()
merged.apply(lambda k: k[0].union(k[1]))

2018-02-02         Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
2018-02-03         Int64Index([4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype='int64')
2018-02-04      Int64Index([8, 9, 10, 11, 12], dtype='int64')
2018-02-05    Int64Index([12, 13, 14, 15, 16], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: maybe just reset_index(), then we do not need the self define function

Comment: Hi there, I am interested in this topic. I get the point of this first step: defining the group by row index. Please, how do you apply aggregation function then on each of these lists?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would concatenate the `start` and `end` data and name the result column `date` such as:

```
df_concat = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df.start,df.end]),columns=['date'])
```

Then I would create a column with index:

```
df_concat['index'] = df_concat.apply(lambda x: x.name,axis=1)
```

And finally a `groupby` and `apply` such as:

```
df_concat.groupby('date')['index'].apply(lambda x: sorted(set(x)))
```

The output is like:

```
date
2018-02-01                     [0]
2018-02-02         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
2018-02-03         [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
2018-02-04      [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
2018-02-05    [12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
2018-02-06                    [16]
Name: index, dtype: object
```

As @RafaelC said, there are many ways, this one is with `apply` and not `aggregate`, and I don't remove the dates with only one value in the corresponding list

Comment: Hi there, I am interested in this topic as well. I am sorry, I raised the same question in the answer above. I get the point of this first step: defining the group by row index. Please, how do you apply aggregation function then on each of these lists? Thanks for any help, bests!